# Pra que serve esse código?

Tags: javascript

Tenho visto essa estrutura ultimamente, no javascript, tentei pesquisar sobre ela mas não consegui respostas concretas. Sei que é um object -eu acho- mas é que eu sou iniciante e não entendi como ela funciona. Principalmente o começo -var PROD {};??.

```
var PROD = {};
PROD.clients = {
  init: function(){},
  method1: function(){}
};
PROD.pages = {
  init: function(){},
  method1: function(){}
};
PROD.accounts = {
  init: function(){},
  method1: function(){}
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isto é a declaração de um objeto vazio:

```
var PROD = {};
```

As demais também são, mas como propriedades desse objeto como novos objetos.

Quanto ao código:

```
PROD.clients = {
  init: function(){},
  method1: function(){}
};
```

Aqui estamos declarando um objeto com dois membros, sendo que os dois são funções. Normalmente este tipo de declaração acontece quando se deseja implementar *callbacks*, ou seja, funções que serão definidas mais tarde em outros trechos do código.

A definição acima é [o construtor da classe `clients`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: É praticamente uma orientação a objeto? Digamos que isso seja um model somente com as funções? Se quisesse daria para colocar um atributo e esse method1 informaria um valor nele, como se fosse um set?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Você não precisa definir todos os membros do objeto como funções. Pode definir como variáveis.

Answer (score 4):

Esse codigo é somente um modelo, um esqueleto de codigo sem nenhuma implementação em si.

O começo var PROD = {}; esta declarando uma classe vazia.

E nas proximas linhas adicionando os modulos para essa clase.

init: function(){}  deve ser implementado nessa função a construção do modulo.

method1: function(){} deve ser implementado o método para esse modulo.

Comment: Só tome cuidado com a terminologia. Os termos *classe*, *módulo* e *método* não são nativos do JavaScript, embora às vezes sejam usados de forma análoga.